# Spring Security's @PreAuthorize causes 415 "Unsupported Media Type" error

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA, Spring Data REST and Spring Security via Java Config in my application. I'm trying to add this @PreAuthorize annotation to the below method in my UserPrefsRESTController.

**Interface:**

```
package com.company.services.rest;

import com.company.server.model.user.preferences.UserPrefs;
import com.company.server.user.prefs.UserPrefsDTO;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@RequestMapping("/api/userprefs")
public interface UserPrefsRESTController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @PreAuthorize("#userPrefs.id == principal.username or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    ResponseEntity<UserPrefsDTO> setUserPrefs(@RequestBody UserPrefs userPrefs);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<UserPrefsDTO> getUserPrefs(@RequestParam String id);
}
```

**Implementation class:**

```
package com.company.services.rest;

import com.company.server.model.user.preferences.UserPrefs;
import com.company.server.user.prefs.UserPrefsDTO;
import com.company.server.user.prefs.UserPrefsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserPrefsRESTControllerImpl implements UserPrefsRESTController {

    @Autowired
    private UserPrefsService userPrefsService;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<UserPrefsDTO> setUserPrefs(UserPrefs userPrefs) {

        UserPrefsDTO response;

        try {
            response = userPrefsService.setUserPrefsValue(userPrefs);
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<UserPrefsDTO> getUserPrefs(String id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userPrefsService.getUserPrefs(id));
    }
}
```

The endpoint properly returns the UserPrefsDTO when the annotation is not present, but when I add the annotation I get the following error

```
{
  "timestamp": 1494518855146,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "path": "/api/userprefs"
}
```

I tried changing the annotation to an @PostAuthorize as well and I get the same error and do not hit my breakpoints inside the method so it's something to do with the fact that the annotation is there rather than it being @PreAuthorize specifically. I also tried several other expressions including just role checking and permitAll() and get the same results. All authenticated requests return the error regardless of whether the authenticated user is an admin, the relevant user (that matches `#userPrefs.id == principal.username`) or another user. I also tried removing `produces = "application/json"` from the @RequestMapping; and adding `consumes = "application/json"`. Both to no avail

Here is the other relevant code

**UserPrefsDTO:**

```
package com.company.server.user.prefs;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserPrefsDTO implements Serializable{

    private String id;
    private String value;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
package com.company.spring.boot;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("runuser").password("password").roles("USER", "RUN").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "RUN", "ADMIN");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin().permitAll().and()
            .logout().permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

**UserPrefsRepository:**

```
package com.company.server.model.repositories;


import com.company.server.model.ModelConstants;
import com.company.server.model.user.preferences.UserPrefs;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@PersistenceContext(name = ModelConstants.DOMAIN_ID)
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "UserPrefs", path = "UserPrefs", itemResourceRel="UserPrefs")
public interface UserPrefsRepository extends JpaRepository<UserPrefs, String> {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    Page<UserPrefs> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @PostAuthorize("returnObject != null && returnObject.id == principal.username or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    UserPrefs findById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

Strangely enough, I am successfully using the same annotation in an event handler that I'm using to catch requests to the Spring Data REST generated endpoints for the UserPrefs object

**UserPrefsEventHandler:**

```
package com.company.server.model.user.preferences;

import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeCreate;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeDelete;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeSave;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryEventHandler;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;

@RepositoryEventHandler
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class UserPrefsEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    @PreAuthorize("#userPrefs.id == principal.username or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public void checkCreateAuthority(UserPrefs userPrefs) {
        System.out.println("checkCreateAuthority");
    }

    @HandleBeforeSave
    @PreAuthorize("#userPrefs.id == principal.username or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public void checkUpdateAuthority(UserPrefs userPrefs) {
        System.out.println("checkUpdateAuthority");
    }

    @HandleBeforeDelete
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public void checkDeleteAuthority(UserPrefs userPrefs) {
        System.out.println("checkDeleteAuthority");
    }

}
```

Note: The above class is being added via a bean in another config file:

```
@Bean
UserPrefsEventHandler userPrefsEventHandler() {
    return new UserPrefsEventHandler();
}
```

What is causing the 415 error?

**Update - Spring Security debug logs:**

```
2017-05-11 11:51:18.784 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.786 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.787 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2017-05-11 11:51:18.787 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2017-05-11 11:51:18.790 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.790 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@27192c6
2017-05-11 11:51:18.790 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.790 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userprefs' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/userprefs'; against '/logout'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userprefs' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userprefs' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2017-05-11 11:51:18.791 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.792 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/userprefs'; against '/login'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.792 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.792 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.794 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'admin'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.795 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2017-05-11 11:51:18.802 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e0123f1f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_RUN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_RUN, ROLE_USER
2017-05-11 11:51:18.802 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.802 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.804 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.804 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e0123f1f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_RUN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_RUN, ROLE_USER'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.804 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.804 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@419074cb
2017-05-11 11:51:18.806 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
2017-05-11 11:51:18.810 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@e0123f1f: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e0123f1f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_RUN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_RUN, ROLE_USER' stored to HttpSession: 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.Session@6c5d0309
2017-05-11 11:51:18.811 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.811 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.811 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.811 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userprefs' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/userprefs'; against '/logout'
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userprefs' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userprefs' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/userprefs; Attributes: [authenticated]
2017-05-11 11:51:18.812 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e0123f1f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_RUN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_RUN, ROLE_USER
2017-05-11 11:51:18.818 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@721d7b2d, returned: 1
2017-05-11 11:51:18.819 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2017-05-11 11:51:18.819 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2017-05-11 11:51:18.819 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userprefs reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2017-05-11 11:51:18.868 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@e0123f1f: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e0123f1f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_RUN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_RUN, ROLE_USER' stored to HttpSession: 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.Session@6c5d0309
2017-05-11 11:51:18.916 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2017-05-11 11:51:18.917 DEBUG 10256 --- [qtp424848797-87] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Strangely I don't see anything related to the error in the debug logs, though I could be overlooking something.

**Update 2 - "multipart/form-data" vs "application/json"**

I have been submitting the request as "multipart/form-data" which is generating the error. When I instead send it as "application/json" the request succeeds. I am still puzzled by the fact that the request works fine when submitting as "multipart/form-data" when the @PreAuthorize annotation is not present. While sending as "application/json" is a sufficient solution to my problem, the question remains as to why this is an issue.

Comment: Do you have any logs with the `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException`? Maybe the stack trace give us some more informations?

Comment: Unfortunately no further logs are being produced other than what's posted and I'm not sure what log level settings I would need to edit to get that information.